# Write XML with String

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

How to to write .xml file with this string?

string:

```
string string1 = textbox1.text;
string string2 = textbox2.text;
string string3 = textbox3.text;
string string4 = textbox4.text;
```

the xml file result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <books>
            <book Title="Pure JavaScript" Price=string1/>
            <book Title="Effective C++" Price=string2/>
            <book Title="Assembly Language: Step-By-Step" Price=string3/>
            <book Title="Oracle PL/SQL Best Practices" Price=string4/>
        </books>
```

Comment: You have 8 different strings in your code sample and because of the default naming we have no idea what each means. It is difficult to see how these are supposed to match up with your XML.

Comment: The XML is also not valid, as the `Price` attributes do not have quotes around the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq to XML for this. Suppose you have a class `Book`:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And now you have a list of books that you want to put into an XML document:

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
books.Add(new Book() { Title = "Pure JavaScript", Price = 59.0M});

XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("books", books.Select( x=> new XElement("book", 
                               new XAttribute("Title", x.Title), 
                               new XAttribute("Price", x.Price)))));
```

Now you can just save this `XDocument`:

```
xdoc.Save("text.xml");
```

This produces:

```
<books>
  <book Title="Pure JavaScript" Price="59.0" />
</books>
```

Comment: sorry, but for create a two <book Title="Pure JavaScript" Price="59.0" /> ?

Comment: Just add another book to the collection: `books.Add(new Book() { Title = "Some other book name", Price = 11.99M});`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the System.Xml namespace.  Particularly XmlDocument and XmlNode

Also XML Literals (I know VB has them, not sure about C#)

Comment: C# doesn't have XML Literals.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these keywords:

1. `XmlWriter`
2. `XDocument`
3. `XmlDocument`
4. Serialization

I think, in your situation `XmlWriter` is the best choice.

Comment: -1 for recommending `XmlTextWriter`, which should no longer be used directly.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, ok, `XmlWriter`. And where did I recommend to use it directly?

Comment: You mentioned it. Why mention it in a list of things to use?